# Laradock problema ao inicializar os containers

Tags: laravel, composer, docker

Instalei o ubuntu 20.04LTS e o dockernativo de linux usando o wsl2 do windows 10 Home.

Baixei o laradock e tentei correr os containers com o comando:

```
docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpmyadmin workspace
```

Mas aparece-me sempre o seguinte erro:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: unrecognised compile-time option bit(s) at offset 0 in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Formatter/OutputFormatter.php:137
```

Já tentei mudar a versão do composer no .env mas sem sucesso, o erro continua.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que poderei estar a fazer mal?

Comment: Questões de configuração de serviços, containers, aplicações e infraestrutura devem ser feitas em inglês no [su], [sf], https://unix.stackexchange.com/ ou mesmo no https://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/ conforme o assunto. Lembre-se de ler as regras específicas de cada comunidade antes de postar lá. Para futuras questões que estejam no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic) vale a pena entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No arquivo Dokerfile da pasta laradock/workspace (Linha 56 aproximadamente), onde tem o trecho:

```
RUN set -xe; \
apt-get update -yqq && \
pecl channel-update pecl.php.net && \
groupadd -g ${PGID} laradock && \
useradd -l -u ${PUID} -g laradock -m laradock -G docker_env && \
usermod -p "*" laradock -s /bin/bash && \
apt-get install -yqq \
```

adicione abaixo de "apt-get install -yqq ", a seguinte linha:

```
libargon2-1 libidn2-0 libpcre2-8-0 libpcre3 libxml2 libzstd1 \
```

Para mim resolveu o problema.
Acredito que por conta de alguma atualização do laradock ou do próprio docker, essas libs passaram a ser necessárias.

Segue fonte da solução:
https://githubmemory.com/repo/laradock/laradock/issues/3103

**Meu docker:**
**Engine: 20.10.10**
**compose: 1.29.2**